# Relational Database Design (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table User that stores user information - such as name, date of birth, locations, etc.

I have also created a link table called User_Options - for the purpose of storing multi-value attributes - this basically stores the checkbox selections.

I have a front-end form for the user to fill in and create their user profile. Here are the tables I have created to generate the checkbox options:

```
Table User_Attributes
=====================
id    attribute_name
---------------------
1     Hobbies
2     Music
```

```
Table User_Attribute_Options
======================================
id    user_attribute_id    option_name 
--------------------------------------
1     1                    Reading
2     1                    Sports
3     1                    Travelling
4     2                    Rock
5     2                    Pop
6     2                    Dance
```

So, on the front-end form there are two sets of checkbox options - one set for Hobbies and one set for Music.

And here are the User tables:

```
Table User
========================
id    name           age
------------------------
1     John           25
2     Mark           32
```

```
Table User_Options
==================================================
id    user_id         user_attribute_id      value
--------------------------------------------------
1     1               1                      1
2     1               1                      2
3     1               2                      4
4     1               2                      5
5     2               1                      2
6     2               2                      4
```

(in the above table 'user_attribute_id' is the ID of the parent attribute and 'value' is the ID of the attribute option).

So I'm not sure that I've done all this correctly, or efficiently. I know there is a method of storing hierarchical data in the same table but I prefer to keep things separate.

My main concern is with the User_Options table - the idea behind this is that there only needs to be one link table that stores multi-value attributes, rather than have a table for each and every multi-value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see that I'd change is that in the association table, User_Options, you have an id that doesn't seem to serve a purpose. The primary key for that table would be all three columns, and I don't think you'd be referring to the options a user has by an id--you'd be getting them by user_id/user_attribute_id. For example, give me all the user options where user  is 1 and user attribute id is 2. Having those records uniquely keyed with an additional field seems extraneous.

I think otherwise the general shape of the tables and their relationships looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with how you've done it.

It's possible to make things more extensible at the price of more linked table references (and in the composition of your queries).  It's also possible to make things flatter, and less extensible and flexible, but your queries will be faster.

But, as is usually the case, there's more than one way to do it.